# Get the length of an array within a JSON object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to find out how many items are in my JSON object. I have seen many answers but they all deal with a common value to loop through. I am wanting the results to tell me that there are 2 items in this object. Any help would be great!

```
[{"manager_first_name":"jim","manager_last_name":"gaffigan"}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) in newer browsers. It would return an array of all the keys in the object, and that array would have a length property that will tell you how many items there are in the object :

```
var arr = [{"manager_first_name":"jim","manager_last_name":"gaffigan"}];

var length = Object.keys(arr[0]).length;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/h974e/)

In non-supporting browsers, you have to iterate

```
var arr = [{"manager_first_name":"jim","manager_last_name":"gaffigan"}];
var i = 0;

for (var key in arr[0]) i++;
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/h974e/1/)

Comment: Thank you, this exactly what I was looking for. Simple and clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var arr = [{"manager_first_name":"jim","manager_last_name":"gaffigan"}],
length = 0,
obj = arr[0]; // Get first obj from array

for(var k in obj){
    if( obj.hasOwnProperty(k) ) {
        length++;
    }
}
console.log(length); // Shows 2
```

You should use `hasOwnProperty` because you can also extend an Object with functions, there could otherwise also be count als keys.

Links:

- [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

Comment: You should only use `.hasOwnProperty` if you *know* the prototype chain of the object has enumerable properties that need to be avoided. And there's no excuse for not knowing this in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var jsonArr = [{"manager_first_name":"jim","manager_last_name":"gaffigan"}];
var itemCount = JSON.stringify(jsonArr).split('":"').length - 1;
```

This is, of course, a rather coarse(and unreliable) way of doing it, but if you just want the item count, this should work like a charm.

Comment: Unless of course there happens to be a `:` character in a key or value.

Comment: Well, yeah, I did say coarse. Also, tricky temperamental things, charms

Comment: But this isn't merely coarse. It's unreliable. There'll be no warning if such a character finds its way in. The result will simply be inaccurate.